# Can I create XSD component without binding any schema file by eclipse xsd API?

Tags: eclipse, xsd

Using [eclipse XSD](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=xsd#xsd) API, I can load a schema file and then parse the related xsd components.

Now my question is, can i create a blank `XSDElementDeclaration` component and set their properties without binding any schema file?

For example, I'd like to create a simple type element named "query":

`<element name = "query" type = "xsd:string"/>`

My code like this:

```
XSDSimpleTypeDefinition queryStr =XSDFactory.eINSTANCE.createXSDSimpleTypeDefinition();
queryStr.setName("string");
queryStr.setTargetNamespace("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

XSDElementDeclaration queryEle  = XSDFactory.eINSTANCE.createXSDElementDeclaration();
queryEle.setName("query");
queryEle.setTypeDefinition(queryStr);
```

I think the created `queryEle` should be meet my requirement. But it seems the created element is incorrect when I returned it to other's use.

How can I create `XSDElementDeclaration` directly using the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still need create XSDParticle and set this element to particle:

```
XSDSchema schemaForSchema =  XSDUtil.getSchemaForSchema(XSDConstants.SCHEMA_FOR_SCHEMA_URI_2001);
XSDSimpleTypeDefinition queryType = schemaForSchema.resolveSimpleTypeDefinition(simpleTypeName);

XSDElementDeclaration queryEle  = XSDFactory.eINSTANCE.createXSDElementDeclaration();
queryEle.setName("query");
queryEle.setTypeDefinition(queryType);

XSDParticle elementParticle = XSDFactory.eINSTANCE.createXSDParticle();
elementParticle.setMinOccurs(minOccurs);
elementParticle.setMaxOccurs(maxOccurs);
elementParticle.setContent(element);
....

//add the element to XSDModelGroup
modelGroup.getContents().add(elementParticle);
```

...